# Multiple UIGestureRecognizers in Xcode/Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uigesturerecognizer

Right now, I have two different UILabels each with their own long press and pan UIGestureRecognizers (setup through the storyboard). My final goal is to have each UILabel change color when long pressed, and without lifting their finger to end the long press, to change the value of the UILabel itself when the user pans up and down or side to side.

Right now, each UILabel has its own pan gesture method and long press gesture method. Is there any way to have a single long press/pan method for both UILabels but also have the ability to do something for one label and something else for another?

Also, is there a better approach to doing this? Eventually, I would also like to implement visual feedback when changing the value of the labels, such as in the form of animations.

I am new to iOS programming and programming in general and detailed answers are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: By coding, what have you tried?

Comment: Right now I have distinct methods for each gesture recognizer and a lot of repeated code. For example, I just changed the UILabel variable in the long press methods so that they acts on the label that is long pressed. I tried extracting information from the sender, with sender.view.tag, but both buttons gave the same tag of 0 and I'm not sure how to set them up to have unique tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a single function.No need to have seperate gestures for seperate Label.Example

```
//First add tag value to ur labels
label_one.tag=1;
label_two.tag=2;


UIPanGestureRecognizer * _panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
_panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
[label_one addGestureRecognizer:_panGestureRecognizer];


 UIPanGestureRecognizer * _panGestureRecognizer_two = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
_panGestureRecognizer_two.delegate = self;
[label_two addGestureRecognizer:_panGestureRecognizer_two];


-(void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender{
     if(sender.tag==1){

     }
     else if(sender.tag==2){
     }
 }
```

Same goes for other gesture as well

Comment: This works only for the second label, but not for the first. I threw in some println() and the first label doesn't even call the handlePanGesture method, while the second label does.